# Android black bar below status bar. What is it?

Tags: android, statusbar

Android 7.0
After installing my app and hockeyapp app I have weird black bar under status bar. What did it? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Upload image please

Comment: Is this a different device? Different screen size? How did you design the layout. Was it to fill space. Or a fixed height that doesnt match.

Comment: It used to fit all space including status bar but now I can find other apps including my bank app and there is black bar too. I attached image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are reffering to the Samsung S8 device.

Inside the Application tag in your manifest, try adding the meta data for max aspect ratio.

```
<application ....
     ....  >
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="5.0"/>
    ....
    ....
</application>
```

> Most devices have rectangular screens whose width is fairly close to their height, ranging from the 4:3 ratio of a traditional television screen to the now-common 16:9 ratio. However, in some situations an app might run on a device with a more extreme aspect ratio.
>
> An app can declare the maximum aspect ratio it is able to support. If the app runs on a device with a more extreme aspect ratio, the system automatically letterboxes the app, leaving portions of the screen unused so the app can run at its specified maximum aspect ratio.

The Samsung S8 has one of these "extreme" aspect ratios, so it must be specified that you support them. Why this is not by default, I don't know

You should be able to overcome this if you target API 24 and above. Otherwise, try setting the max aspect ratio to something greater than the recommended minimum of 2.1.

> Note: You do not need to set a maximum aspect ratio if an activity's android:resizeableActivity attribute is set to true. If your app targets API level 24 or higher, this attribute defaults to true. For more information, see Configuring your app for multi-window mode

[Android documentation about the issue can be found here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#MaxAspectRatio)

Comment: Hey it worked! thanks! But you should use 
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="5.0"/> rather than "5"

Comment: @mihau87 I've changed it to "5.0" as suggested. please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: @mihau87 please click the "green tick" next to the answer :-)

Comment: You can refer to this document: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html In addition, you cannot test black statusbar problem in Android Studio emulator. The manufacturers like Samsung and LG added something effect that the emulator does not have.